# Is it possible to get GNU sed for OSX?

Tags: macos, unix

I have brew installed but I don't have the GNU flavor of sed - can I get it through brew?

Comment: `fsed`?  Did you mean that or `sed`?

Comment: Or did you mean fuse?

Comment: @Tony Williams, Since there is no GNU fuse, not to be confused with libfuse on GNU Hurd, and the OP was asking about GNU fsed it is more likely just a typo and he simply meant GNU sed.

Comment: @user3439894 - I'm sorry, but his question doesn't say "GNU fsed" it just says "fsed". You are correct that the typo is more likely to be from "sed" but it could be something else, including "fuse".

Comment: @Tony Williams, The subject line says "**Is it possible to get gnu fsed for OSX?**"!  I just properly wrote GNU in upper case in my previous comment to you.  I seriously doubt the OP meant fuse!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, everyone.  Someone had renamed their GNU sed to "fsed" because they got it through "fink." :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you said `fsed` however I could not find it anywhere so assuming it's a typo and you actually meant `sed` you can install it with:

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

Or

```
brew install gnu-sed --with-default-names
```

Comment: You might also want to say that `sed` is already installed and that the OS X one is almost certainly good enough since `sed` is so old that any differences between the BSD `sed` installed and GNU `sed` will be minor, if any.

Comment: @Tony Williams, There **are** differences between BSD and GNU versions of sed as well as other utilities and why many of us install the GNU versions under OS X in order to take advantage of the differences.  Especially when coding various scripts that need to run under OS X and Linux and prefer coding for the latest GNU versions.

Comment: @TonyWilliams, for a concrete case of a difference that mattered, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/31151156/107090.

Comment: Portability does not require the installation of a newer version of software or a different package of the same name. BSD sed statements and GNU sed statements can both be written so they work in both environments. I think that this is Tony's point.

Comment: AFAIC because I work in both environments and like using the latest stable release of most things use I have found it much easier to **not** use many of OS X's BSD programs when it's easier to use latest stable GNU or even later version of other non BSD programs.  Those of us that install different version of the same programs found in OS X do it for good reasons, were not just doing it because it can be done.  That said, it's besides the point anyway as the OP wanted to install GNU sed even thought OS X comes with an old version of BSD sed and I gave him the appropriate commands to do so!