# How to install GNU-sed?

Tags: install, bash, unix, homebrew

I am trying to install GNU sed. Following [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195590/is-it-possible-to-get-gnu-sed-for-osx) I did

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

A priori it went fine, but then the command `gsed` is not found. I could not find any `gnu-sed` (or equivalent) in `/usr/local/bin/` except the standard `sed`.

I am on Mac OS X 10.11.3

Comment: Try using `find` to _find_ it.  In Terminal, use the following command: `find /usr -type f -name *sed`

Comment: Searching this way and selecting on those containing the term `gnu`, I found `/usr/local/Cellar/gnu-sed/4.2.2/bin/sed`. Should I just move this file to `/usr/local/bin/`? Thanks

Comment: The OS X BSD version should be `/usr/bin/sed`, so I see no reason why you can't copy/move the GNU version to `/usr/local/bin/`. That said, depending on which is in your `PATH` first is the one that going to run if you don't do something to differentiate the two. Maybe call the GNU version `gsed`.

Comment: Do I just have to rename the file `sed` to `gsed` to rename the command?

Comment: The filename and the command name are essentially the same thing, so you can rename the file or not, that's up to you. You could also just leave the file where it is and create a symlink to it, named however you want. If you leave both named `sed` and both are in the `PATH`, then one is going to run over the other based on the `PATH`. If you don't understand what I'm saying, then you need to do some Googling.

Comment: I don't know indeed what the `PATH` is but I'll investigate that tomorrow. I'll also try moving this file tomorrow (I'm not on the same computer now). I think you can make an answer out of your comments if you want. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would appear that the `brew` link process didn't successfully link from the Cellar to `/usr/local/bin`.

First, let's check that it installed. Try `brew list` and you will get a list of installed formulae. If `gnu-sed` is in there then it installed okay. If it's not, then run `brew install gnu-sed` again and you should be okay.

If it is in the list then try linking it and see what output you get. `brew link gnu-sed` will do this. It should link okay and you will be off and running.

Comment: Thanks. I did as you said. I also unlinked an relinked gnu-sed (`brew unlink gnu-sed && brew link gnu-sed`) and got `Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/gnu-sed/4.2.2... 3 symlinks removed;Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gnu-sed/4.2.2... 3 symlinks created`. However the commands `gnu-sed` and `gsed` are still not found and I don't think the `sed` command has been replaced.

Comment: Are you sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH`?

Comment: When I do `echo $PATH` I get `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin` which seems pretty bad. All other bash commands work fine though.

Comment: OK, your PATH is OK. Does /usr/local/bin/gsed exist? 

What happens if you `cd /usr/local/bin` and then `ln ../Cellar/gnu-sed/4.2.2/bin/gsed /usr/local/bin/gsed` ?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/gsed` does not exist.  I only have `/usr/local/bin/sed`. `/usr/local/Cellar/gnu-sed/4.2.2/bin/gsed` does not exist either. Your `ln` command therefore returns `No such file or directory`. Thanks for keeping up with my issue :)